# How can I customize w3-button-hover class in w3school css framework?

Tags: css

In w3schools CSS framework there are some predefined buttons and predefined settings for this buttons. I've already changed the color of them by adding to my HTML file the .class(.w3-button) in the style element at the head section but I cannot do the same with hover settings.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.w3-button {
      background-color: #8B4513;
      box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px  black;
      border-radius: 4px;
      color:black;
      }
      
  .w3-hover-green { <!-- I've tried to that but it didnt work -->
  background-color: #D2691E;
  color: white;
}
 </style>
 
 <body>
 <p><button class= "w3-button w3-hover-green"> button </button> </p>
```

Any idea?

Comment: `.w3-button:hover` ?

Comment: Already tried that, but still not working

Comment: .w3-hover-green:hover {
    color: #fff!important;
    background-color: #4CAF50!important;
}

Comment: The :hover selector seems not to be working at all

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47619214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to override the `w3-button` hover style in W3.CSS is to use the CSS `!important` exception.

Although I believe `!important` [should be avoided whenever possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception), this is actually how the "official" W3.CSS custom themes work, as you can see on the [W3.CSS Color Generator](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_color_generator.asp) page.

A simplified example:

```css
      
a.custom-hover-color:hover { 
  background-color: orange !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<a class= "w3-button w3-green custom-hover-color"> click me </a>
```

EDIT:

In some cases it may be necessary to use cascade layers to override the `!important` styles, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#avoiding_and_overriding_!important).

For example, here we use the fact that an `!important` *layered* author style has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#complete_cascade_order) than an `!important` *unlayered* author style, to make sure a custom color persists during hover:

```css
@layer moreImportant {
  .my-color {
    background-color: purple !important;
    color: lightsalmon !important;
  }
}

.w3-button:hover {
  filter: brightness(150%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<a class="w3-button my-color"> hover here </a>
```

We could also use layer order, and `@import` w3.css into a separate layer *below* the `moreImportant` layer.

More insight:

- [CSS cascade order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#complete_cascade_order)
- [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- [How to override `!important`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11178673)

Answer (score 0):

Hey in the last section of code the `<p><button class= "w3-button (ADD A DOT HERE)w3-hover-green"> button </button> </p>` please add a dot before the "w3-hover-green"

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. You mean to do class=w3-button .w3-hover-green" ?. If that is what you mean, it didn't work.

Comment: That's weird becuase I went in the w3schools own type editor and tried it and it worked fine for me..

Comment: https://ibb.co/jhQNHFW As you can see, the button turns into grey which is not the color that I'm specifying  at the .w3-hover-green class in the style element.

Comment: Oh just figured it out, please change the text in .w3-hover-green to .w3-hover-white in order to get white. So :    ```.w3-hover-white { <!-- I've tried to that but it didnt work -->
  background-color: #D2691E;
  color: white; ```

Comment: And remember to change the last column of code aswell to  ```<p><button class= "w3-button w3-hover-white"> button </button> </p> ```